# Is there no way to handle encoding with Data.Text.IO.hGetContents?

Tags: haskell, text, encoding, utf-8

When I try to read a UTF8 text file as `Text`, I attempted to use `Data.Text.IO.readFile`.
However, when the locale of system environment is not `*.UTF8` (especially `c`), it does not work.
It says `hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)`

Yes, I read Locale support part in document `Data.Text.IO`.
It says `Data.Text.IO` depends on the settings on system environment.

Therefore, I tried to use `Data.Text.IO.hGetContents` functions with `System.IO.hSetEncoding h System.IO.utf8_bom`.
This works when I used it with `System.IO.hGetContents`.

However, with `Data.Text.IO.hGetContents`, it says `text: <stdout>: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)`.

Is there no way to handle encoding with `Data.Text.IO.hGetContents` or `Data.Text.IO.readFile` without changing system environment variable such as `LANG`?
The method just editing Haskell code is preferred.

Here is my original code:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

main = do
  text <- T.readFile "./data.md"
  T.putStrLn text
```

And here is my trial code:

```
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

import System.IO

main = do
  h <- System.IO.openFile "./data.md" System.IO.ReadMode
  System.IO.hSetEncoding h System.IO.utf8_bom
  text <- T.hGetContents h -- `System.IO.hGetContents h` works!
  T.putStrLn text
```

These works when the locale of a system is `*.UTF8`, and fails with other environments.

Tested environment informations:

- Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)
- GHC 7.10.3
- `text` 1.2.2.0

Comment: For anyone who needs random non-ASCII in `data.md` to test this: `äüöÄÜÖßáéúíóð¾‹èÉµ€†¤r’`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm getting a bit different error:

```
<stdout>: hPutChar: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

I'm getting the same error even with `System.IO.hGetContents`. Not sure why the behavior is different for you.
(I'm using `ghc-7.10.2` and `text-1.2.1.3`)

To answer the question: You are trying to send `UTF-8`-encoded string to `stdout`, configured for `ASCII`. I'm not sure what it should output.

If your terminal actually accepts `UTF-8`, then you can configure `stdout` to ignore the current locale and accept `UTF-8`:

```
main = do
  h <- System.IO.openFile "./data.md" System.IO.ReadMode
  System.IO.hSetEncoding h System.IO.utf8_bom
  text <- T.hGetContents h
  System.IO.hSetEncoding stdout System.IO.utf8_bom
  T.hPutStrLn stdout text
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me. I think my environment accepts `UTF-8` for `stdout`. I tested this sample code to deploy a Linux service by upstart.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to read the file with `bytestring` and use `text-icu` for {en,de}coding. (This is alluded to in the `text` documentation: "To use an extended and very rich family of functions for working with Unicode text..., see the `text-icu` package".) For example, the following Haskell file reads my test file correctly with both `LANG=en_US.utf8` and `LANG=C`:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.Text.ICU.Convert as ICU

import System.IO

main = do
    -- dunno what the Nothing argument is for, read the docs!
    conv <- ICU.open "utf-8" Nothing
    h    <- openFile "test.txt" System.IO.ReadMode
    bs   <- BS.hGetContents h
    print (ICU.toUnicode conv bs)
```

N.B. I have called `print` rather than `T.putStrLn` -- as the output to my terminal would depend on the locale otherwise!